# Process is going slower after converting HashMap<String..> into HashMap<Integer...>

Tags: java, string, optimization, hashmap, integer

I have a dataset where i used to save to maps the ids of userid, storeid, reviewid like `HashMap<String (userid), Double(Something to save)>`

The process was iterating in reasonable time, but i had a problem with memory so i had to change the HashMap into `HashMap<Integer(userid), Double(Something to save)>` that means that i saved the String userids into Integer like this:

while iterating the dataset where `userids= HashMap<String, Integer>`

```
    if(!userids.containsKey(userid)){
        userids.put(userid, uid);
        uid++;
    }
```

I do not want to post the whole code because i think the problem is not there. The main idea is that i converted the String ids into Integer ids and then I followed the process in the same way that i did before, only the Strings are now Integers.

For example, in the case where i had Strings, i Had a map lets set `wholeSetHistory<String, HashMap<String, Double>>` where the first String is userid the second a storeid and the Double is a user Rate. Now the map is
`wholeSetHistory<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Double>>` with the way i mentioned before. The process had gone slower by 20 times...

If you need more code please let me know! Thanks

Comment: Try to profile your application, you will get exact answer for what makes your application slower: https://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html

Comment: I know where my application is going slow but i do not why. As i said the process is the exact same with only difference the change of String keys into Integer keys. Thank you for your interest : )

Comment: In that case HashMap with Integer key uses bad Hash Function producing a lot of equal results which known as collision. Can you check this? Try to switch on TreeMap. If treemap will increase performance, then indeed Hash Function for Integer is bad.

Comment: Ok Anatolys, I will try that later because i have to go now.. thanks again!